# I Want to Check Text Field

Tags: html, asp-classic

I am a beginner in HTML and ASP and I should write a program that when username and password are admin and user click on the button, the program opens a new ASP page in otherwise the program shows invalid username or password in table.

I write this code but always when I click on the Button, the program shows new ASP page! 
I write this code in notepad.

```
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="Exam1.asp">
    <table cellpadding="20" border="1" align="center" style="text-align:left;">
        <colorgroup>
        <col style="background-color:pink">
            <col style="background-color:pink">
        </colorgroup>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>UserName:</p>
                <p>Password:</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Username">
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="password" name="Password">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Button"></td>
            <td>
                <%If Session("Username")="admin"&Session("Password")="admin" Then%>
                    <form method="post" action="Exam1.asp">
                    </form>
                <%Else%>
                    Invalid username or password.
                <%End If%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for help.
Cheers

Comment: What does it say when you hover over the [homework] tag?

Comment: Your current logic is plain wrong; I advice you to go back to the drawing board. Basically you should: have the user submit name and password; read those details using `Request.Form()`; if valid put them in Session variables and redirect to different page otherwise (invalid name or password) just show a message and let the user input different details.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the submit button named `Button`, it will take you to `Exam1.asp` and send it the information the user typed into the form. `Sesson("Username")` and `Sesson("Password")` are not yet defined in your code, but in `Exam1.asp` they will hold the data that the user typed.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.How can i define a session?