# Why the program not run correctly?

Tags: html, asp-classic

I am beginner to html and asp. I should write code of the program in Notepad. I want the program that when I click on the Random Button, generate a random number and when I click on the Check button, the program compare between my guess and random number. I write this code but when run the program, not show random number and not compare. Why?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

var numOfGuess=new number(0);
var numRandom;
var num;

function RandomNum(){
 numRandom=new number(math.floor(math.random()*100));
 response.write(numRandom);
 numOfGuess=0;
}

 fucntion Guess(){
 num=document.getElementById("guess");
 var alert=""; 
 if(num.value<numRand){
   alert="grater than!";
   numOfGuess++;
 }
 esle if (num.value>numRand){
  alert="lower than!";]
  numOfGuess++;
 }
 else{
  alert="equal!";
  numOfGuess++;

}
document.getElementById("message").innerHtml=alert;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="guess">
<input type="submit" onClick='RandomNum()' value="Random">

<p id="message"></p>

<input type="submit" onClick='Guess()' value="Check">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043119/i-want-to-check-text-field#comment19417836_14043119) apply to this case as well. You lack the most basic understanding of what is classic ASP and what is server side vs.client side code. The only way we can help you is give you everything, but that won't serve any purpose. You need to *learn* yourself.

Comment: There is Syntax error in writing function spelling. There are lots more of Syntax Error. plz check.

Comment: Don't use homework tag as [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: learn 1 thing at a time EMA. Start with HTML.

Comment: Thanks my friend. I don't know about html and asp. I start learn this with w3schools. If you can, suggest to me a link or site for begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like AnthonyLeGovic said:

> you need to be rigorous when programming

here is what you are looking for:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script language="javascript">
        var numRand = 0;
        var numGuess = 0;
        var numTry = 1;

        function setRand(){
            numRand = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
            numTry = 0;
            alert("done");
        }

        function guess(){
            var msg = document.getElementById("message");
            numGuess=Number(document.getElementById("guess").value);
            if(numGuess>numRand){
                msg.innerHTML = "lower than!";
            }
            else if(numGuess<numRand){
                msg.innerHTML = "grater than!";
            }
            else {
                msg.innerHTML = "equal! tried " + numTry +"times";
            }
            numTry++;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="guess" />
    <input type="button" onclick="setRand()" value="Random" />
    <p id="message"></p>
    <input type="button" onclick="guess()" value="Check" />
</body>
```

do not forget `language="javascript"` in your script tag else your script will not work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be rigorous when programming.

There are some syntax errors in your code like :

- **fucntion** instead of **function** while declaring Guess function.
- you declare numRandom as a global variable but you are using numRand then, unfortunately these two variables are not the same at all. Moreover numRand isn't declare (which is logic because it should be numRandom).
- you are using innerHtml instead of **innerHTML** (case sensitive) in order to help the user to find the right number.

Maybe there are some more mistakes I've forgotten right there.

Comment: Thanks for help. I correct these but still not run and has error!

Comment: Which errors are you still having? I think you can easily find them and correct it using Firebug